# UDP_broad_2uni receive ECLIPSE_UDP_SERVER EXCEPTIONHost is down - Android

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, chord

I'm using Chord SDK with Eclipse Kepler, a virtual device and Chord Relay Server for Android. I've followed the instructions from this tutorial, http://developer.samsung.com/chord, "Chord SDK Emulator Guide ver1.2".

Why am I seeing this error message in the Chord Relay Server output, "UDP_broad_2uni receive ECLIPSE_UDP_SERVER EXCEPTIONHost is down"?